# Problems installing Freya on Acer Aspire 9412SMi

Tags: system-installation

I've been using elementary OS Luna 32bit for a year in my Acer Aspire 9412WSMi, no problem. I can install it at any time. But I cannot install Freya 32bit.

I've used both bootable DVD disks and USB sticks. Even if I use the Smart Boot Manager (usb image, with unetboting) from sbm.bin disk image I get a message on my screen:

```
[1.649601] Corrupted low memory at c000c6cc (c6cc phys) = 00000108
[1.649682] Memory corruption detected in low memory
```

Install stops soon. 
I've updated BIOS from V1.05 to V1.24 from Acer.

Comment: Can you run a memory test from within your BIOS?

Comment: I don't have a USB key handy to test this on but when you first boot and see the little keyboard and man circle thing at the bottom of the screen (before the elementaryOS logo) hit a key. It should show up some advanced boot options. 1 of which is memtest. There should be another option where you can feed boot options to your kernel. Try adding `memory_corruption_check_size=128K` or 256K

Comment: [This link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions) explains it better than I did. ;p

Comment: I passed Memtest86 and everything seems fine: "Pass complete, no errors, press ESC to exit"
F6 shows some options that I don't change. On the lower part of the screen: 
Boot Options boot= casper only-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash -- (here I add memory_corruption_check_size=128K  or 256K, or even zeroK.). I hope it is the correct place.
I get then the old message about memory corrupted and again the install process stops in a while.

Comment: Do you have more than 4GB Ram? Would be my first guess... If so, you will have to use a 64 bit OS. However it would be strange you were able to install/use Luna 32 bit!

Comment: Have you tried new elementary 0.3.1?

Comment: Installing 64 bit is not an option, [as the processor does not support it](http://ark.intel.com/de/products/27233/Intel-Core-Duo-Processor-T2300-2M-Cache-1_66-GHz-667-MHz-FSB).

Answer (score 1):

According to a [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/324894/comments/37) on a [similar error message](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/324894) in Ubuntu  (elementary OS 0.3 is based on Ubuntu 14.04), changing `memory_corruption_check_size` in the [boot options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions) **could** solve the issue, maybe:

```
 memory_corruption_check_size=128K
```

instead of the default

```
 memory_corruption_check_size=64K
```

Note, this is a shot in the dark and I am not sure how to edit Boot Options in elementary. (If someone knows, please edit my question accordingly.)